# Run integration test from IDE and cmd line fails with JHipster jwt secret empty

Tags: integration-testing, jhipster

I'm running a micro service architecture with a problem on running some of the integration tests.
Running JHipster 5.0.2 on Mac against MySQL db.
LogsResourceIntTest is one example (generated by Jhipster with no modifications).
The following code aborts with a NP

```
        this.secretKey = encoder.encodeToString(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getAuthentication().getJwt()
        .getSecret().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

I have debugged it and the properties for the timeouts are set, but the token (secret) is empty.
Token is set in my /src/test/resource/application-test.yml file.
Running the test from cmd line also aborts with a NP. Running tests as follows:

```
./mvnw clean install -Dprofile=test
```

Any pointers on how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

There's no such "test" profile in JHipster, so it can't be "generated by JHipster with no modifications". Using a profile that does not exist, you get properties from default profile.

Properties for tests are read from `src/test/resources/config/application.yml` because of test classpath.

Comment: Running with dev profile also gives same result. TokenProvider cannot be constructed and thus the Security config aborts.
This in turn aborts the compile process.
The only way to get the module compiled is to skip the tests with -DskipTests option.

Comment: If you did not make any change then you could share the project on github.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem in the yml file.
Updated the file with some of my application's properties and had a format error.
I have used "test" profile" on other SpringBoot apps to help identify which files must be included for configuration. Reverted all back to default and fixed error in yml.
Will look at another way of identifying specific config files. The unit tests needs some of the Spring beans, but the integration test needs all (most of them).
Used the maven surefire and failsafe to split them before. I'm integrating to Google Pub/Sub and don't need all of that configured when doing unit tests.

Thank you for the help.